# Using jQuery to extract CDATA in XML for use as HTML

Tags: html, jquery, xml

[image: HIER IST cDATA FILE]

Hey guys, I am trying to get only the text from the p tag inside of CDATA for description. I could render Cdata in my code component but the `<p>` tag is still inside of the text. I want to only render the first P tag Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://somethignsomething.com",
      dataType:'xml',
      type:'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            
            var my_blog = $(result).find('channel item').first();
       
                console.log(result)
               // var my_link = my_blog.find('link').parent().attr('href');;
              //  var my_link = my_blog.find('link').attr('href');
                var my_title = my_blog.find('title').text();
               
                var my_description = my_blog.find('description').text();
               
                var img = my_blog.find('content\\:encoded, encoded').text();
                img = $.parseHTML(img);
                img = img[0].firstChild.src;
                var oldSrc = 'https://cdn11.net/m/resources/img/teaser/rht-full-blogteaser-medium-smartphones-290x268.jpg';
                var newSrc = img;
                $('img[src="' + oldSrc + '"]').attr('src', img);
            
                

            $('.text-content').replaceWith( 
                $('<h2 />',{
                    text: my_title
                }),
                $('<p />',{
                    text: my_description
                }),
                )           
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It would help us if you show a small but complete, representative sample of XML you are trying to process together with the resulting HTML markup you want to extract/create from that sample.

Comment: @MartinHonnen hey dude sure i edited my quation with xml file image

Answer (score 1):

If you feed the content of `my_description` to the HTML parser with e.g.

```
const htmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(my_description, 'text/html');
```

and select the first `p` element with

```
const p = htmlDoc.querySelector('p');
```

you have a `p` element DOM node.

I am not sure whether you want to insert that `p` element into another element (doable with `target.appendChild(p)` as a core DOM method) or read out its text with `p.textContent` and insert that somewhere.

Comment: thank you so much it works well :) i was thinking to solve problem with regex but i dont even need it with your solution thansk again :)